# RSpec in Rails has "MyString" Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My RSpec tests keep getting these "MyString" attributes popping up. People have said this has to do with fixtures, but I don't use them. I removed the `test` directory, but the problem persists. I'm using Fabrication for Factories/Fabricators. I'm also using Devise's test helpers.

Here's my controller spec that has the problem:

```
it "allows you to see your posts" do
  sign_in Fabricate(:user)
  Fabricate(:post)
  get 'by_me'
  @posts.first.song.should eq "The Sound of Settling"
end
```

And here's my Post Factory/Fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:post) do
  song   "The Sound of Settling"
  artist "Death Cab for Cutie"
  album  "Transatlantism"
  username "foo"
end
```

And my User Factory/Fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  username "foo"
  password "password"
  password_confirmation "password"
end
```

And here's the failure message:

```
  1) PostsController allows you to see your posts
     Failure/Error: Post.first.song.should eq "The Sound of Settling"

       expected: "The Sound of Settling"
            got: "MyString"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How might I fix this?

Comment: Check `spec/factories` or some similar folder.

Comment: @Dogbert I edited it with more info.

Comment: Have you tried `grep -r "MyString" .` from the project root dir to see if it's hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: @iain Nothing hardcoded, just checked. This is part of Rails, it does this sometimes with fixtures, but I'm not using them.

Comment: @iain The ones I didn't accept were when I was new to the site, I accept answers when they're acceptable. For example, someone recommended using `try`, which might not be the best idea.

Comment: @weddingcakes If it's part of Rails then you need to grep the vendor/gem directory and find out why. I'd suggest using `bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor` instead of the defaults Rails uses, as it prevents gems bleeding into other projects.

Comment: @iain I checked that, it's only in the Rails "getting started" guides included with the gem. I also already installed gems in `vendor`.

Comment: Does your test database contain rows with that data ? are you cleaning the database between test runs (eg databasecleaner) ?

Comment: I have no idea what happened, but the problem is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what happened, but the problem's gone.